# Запрет отправки пустого поля на почту

Tags: javascript, php

Друзья подскажите понятную проверку на заполненность поля и его не отправки на почту, переискал кучу вариантов но применить на свое коде не получается

```html
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user__name'];
$phone = $_POST['user__phone'];
$email = $_POST['user__email'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                         // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '************'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = '(**********)'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('**********'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('*******');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = 'Имя: ' .$name . '<br>Номер телефона: ' .$phone. '<br>Почта: ' .$email;
$mail->AltBody = '';

$email = ( isset( $_POST['user__email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['user__email'] ) : true );

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (!$name)` { неотправка }`.

Comment: ))) не отправка ? )

Answer (score 0):

```
  $mail->Body = ($name?'Имя: ' .$name . '<br>':'').($phone?'Номер телефона: ' .$phone . '<br>':'').($email?'Почта: ' .$email:'');
```

Или

```
$mail->Body = '';
if($name) {
   $mail->Body .=  'Имя: ' .$name . '<br>';
}
...
```

Или

```
$data = array();
if($_POST['user__name']) {
    $data['name'] = 'Имя: ' .$_POST['user__name'];
}
...
$mail->Body = implode('<br>',$data);
```